# Print grep result on the same line

Tags: bash, grep

i've grep like:

```
cat /app/REPOCONF/md*|egrep "^OS|PKGINFO"


OS# SunOS md654xxx 5.11 11.4.15.5.0 sun4v sparc sun4v
PKGINFO#            Version: 11.4 (Oracle Solaris 11.4.15.5.0)
```

i want result like

```
OS# SunOS md654xxx 5.11 11.4.15.5.0 sun4v sparc sun4v PKGINFO#  Version: 11.4 (Oracle Solaris 11.4.15.5.0)
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

don´t know if it could help you, but you could try to pipe your grep command with:

```
| tr -d '\n'
```

But maybe you should take a look at `sed` or `awk` for lower cost of comp.

Comment: you can also use `paste -sd' '` ... depends on whether trailing newline should be preserved or not

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /app/REPOCONF/md* | awk '/^OS/ || /^PKGINFO/ { gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",$0);printf "%s ",$0 } END { printf "\n" }'
```

Using awk, search for lines starting with OS or PKGINFO. Strip out multiple spaces and substitute them for single ones. Print the line appending a space at the end.

Comment: i want \n after pkginfo like OS# SunOS md654xxx 5.11 11.4.15.5.0 sun4v sparc sun4v PKGINFO#  Version: 11.4 (Oracle Solaris 11.4.15.5.0)      \n   OS# SunOS md654xxx 5.11 11.4.15.5.0 sun4v sparc sun4v PKGINFO#  Version: 11.4 (Oracle Solaris 11.4.15.5.0)

Comment: OK, I've amended the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just replace `\n` with a space but keep internal spaces:

```sh
cat /app/REPOCONF/md* | egrep "^OS|PKGINFO" | while read ln; do echo -n "$ln "; done
```

If you don't care about the internal spaces, and can accept collapsing consecutive spaces into one:

```sh
rslt=( $(cat /app/REPOCONF/md* | egrep "^OS|PKGINFO") ) echo "${rslt[*]}"
```